# ASSEMBLY 8086 EXERCISE UNIVERSITY

Tags: assembly, intel, x86-16

is anyone able to develop a procedure in an assembly program for intel 8086 processor that reads a vector of integers from data segment and replaces the first DIM/2 elements of the vector with the defined VAL value of the data segment ?

I tried to write something:

```
STACKSEGMENT SEGMENT PUBLIC 'DATACLASS'
    DB 8 DUP(O)
STACKSEGMENT ENDS
DATASEGMENT SEGMENT PUBLIC 'DATACLASS'
    VECTOR  DW 4 DUP (?)
    DIM     DW 4
    VAL     DW 5
DATASEGMENT ENDS
MYCODESEG SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODECLASS'
MYPROC PROC NEAR
ASSUME CS: MYCODESEG, DS:DATASEGMENT, SS:STACKSEGMENT

MOV AX, DATASEGMENT
MOV DS, AX
LEA AX, VECTOR
PUSH AX
MOV AX, DIM
PUSH AX
MOV AX, VAL
PUSH AX
CALL MYPROC
ADD SP,10

mov ah, 4Ch
int 21h

MYCODESEG ENDS
END MYPROC
END
```

Comment: The answer to your question is: "Yes, somebody is surely able to to that." If you have a specific question about your own code, please [edit] your question and post it here.

Comment: Ok I added my code

Comment: Since i'm not english speaking dude :( I don't understand this part `and replaces the first DIM/2 elements`... ? Program should read 4 dw values from command line to `vector` array? And change first 2 elements of `vector` with `VAL`? :/

Comment: According to your question, there's no mention of I/O.  It just says to "reads a vector of integers from data segment", not read from the keyboard or command line and store there.  Of course, what it says next (replace the first half of the elements) doesn't require any reading the array at all, just storing, so it doesn't make sense that you're supposed to read the vector/array *from* the data segment.

Comment: You're got what seems like a call to `myproc`, located inside `myproc`. Looks like this function is going to be an endless recursion. Unless I'm reading this wrong, I'm not familiar with this assembler dialect.

Answer (score 1):

```
MOV AX, DATASEGMENT
MOV DS, AX
LEA AX, VECTOR
PUSH AX
MOV AX, DIM
PUSH AX
MOV AX, VAL
PUSH AX
CALL MYPROC
ADD SP,10
```

If you're trying to read the contents of `VECTOR` into `AX`, this isn't going to do it.

---

```
MOV AX, DATASEGMENT
MOV DS, AX
```

This is correct.

---

```
LEA AX, VECTOR
PUSH AX
```

This, however, won't get you to the contents of `VECTOR`. `LEA` stands for "load effective address". Remember that the label `VECTOR` is just *where* the data is stored - not the data itself. Essentially you've just done

```
mov ax, offset VECTOR
push ax
```

which doesn't really get you any closer to what you want. On this CPU, you actually can't use `ax` to read from memory like that. Only `bx`, `bp`, `si`, and `di` can.
So here's what you're really looking for:

```
MOV AX, DATASEGMENT
MOV DS, AX
LEA SI, VECTOR
MOV AX, [SI]
```

Putting the brackets around `SI` is what makes it a memory load operation. This takes the first 16-bit value in your vector array and loads it into `AX`. Without the brackets there, i.e. `MOV AX, SI`, you'd just be moving the address of your vector array into AX which doesn't achieve anything.

Now that being said, you declared `VECTOR` as `VECTOR DW 4 DUP (?)` which tells the assembler "I need 4 words of space here, but I don't care what the values are right now because the code I'm going to write is going to fill them in." So reading that data right from the start isn't going to accomplish anything of value. You'll get *something* into `ax` with the code example above, but there's no guarantee that the data you get has any real meaning.

---